# walk through all components in model

Tags: openmdao

I have a fairly large model with components grouped hierarchically about 3 levels deep. It would be useful for me to be able recursively iterate through my components and list inputs and outputs, as well as all the option values, and format all that data to my liking so I can make a nice report with it.

calling list_inputs() and list_outputs() on a given group sort of does what I want, in that it prints off the inputs and outputs, but if you call it on a large group you can't get the inputs and outputs of single component next to each other on the page.

I could probably reverse engineer how list_inputs() is working itself but was wondering if there is an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, [`list_inputs`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.16.0/features/debugging/listing_variables.html) and `list_outputs` are both methods defined on the [`System`](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/core/system.py#L3601) class. Thought these methods do group their print-outs by component, the challenge is that you get all the inputs first, then all the outputs. You can't easily see the inputs and outputs for a single component together.

Both of these methods can have their printing shut off by setting `out_stream=None`, and each of them [returns a list of variable data](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.16.0/features/debugging/listing_variables.html?highlight=get_io_metadata#get-list-via-return-value) that you can manually parse through. That may not give you the format you want though.

If you want to manually recurse over the hierarchy and write your own custom report method, then you should look at the following methods on System (i.e. components and groups):

- [get_io_metadata](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/abf17434323557b7c33a49cead644a64793483ad/openmdao/core/system.py#L3279)
- [system_iter](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/abf17434323557b7c33a49cead644a64793483ad/openmdao/core/system.py#L2431)

Those, combined with the data returned from `list_inputs` and `list_outputs` should give you what you need.

Comment: thank you Justin! system_iter() is exactly what I need